# Пролистывание XML путем ScrollView

Tags: xml, android, android-scrollview

Нород, нужна ваша помощь! Хочу, чтобы моя XML пролистывалась путем ScrollView, затем TextView был в TOP, ProgressBar и VideoView посередине. Никак не могу добиться желаемого. HELP новичку, plz.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/webtextview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@color/background_floating_material_light" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prog"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос сформулирован не очень. Я так понял, что надо, чтобы TextView был над видео, а видео на прогрессом?

Если так, то поменяйте фраме на рэлативъ и укажите какому элементу быть над каким:

1) TextView дайте атрибут

```
android:layout_above="@id/video"
```

2) VideoView соответственно:

```
android:layout_above="@id/prog"
```

Так они должны будут выстроиться один над другим.

---

Ну или почему бы не воспользоваться LinearLayout c

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: если делать С Relative и Linear, то все элементы видны, а VideoView куда то исчезает и его нет в лэйауте будто бы....

Comment: @sviter-pro, это потому, что у вашего текстВью высота **match_parent**

Comment: Все ровно его просто напросто нет!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Поставьте у VideoView высоту `wrap_content` или задайте явную. Вообще у элементов, лежащих в контейнере ScrollView, нельзя задавать высоту в `match_parent`.